# Auto adjust layouts after restoring iOS status bar

Tags: ios, layout, storyboard

After initially designing my UIViewControllers in storyboard without a status bar, I have been instructed that we need to put them back in.  Now all the layouts overlap the status bar.  Is there an easy way to have everything automatically adjust to start with y=0 below the status bar? Moving and re-pinning everything to the top layer guide is going to be both tedious and error prone - seems like it should happen automatically.

I am using Xcode 6.1, targeting iOS 7.1 and later.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is just one way to make a script to rewrite Storyboard XML file. You try to change  constraints for one ViewController manually and check the difference.

Comment: Thanks.  That would probably work.  But I guess it suggests that such a built-in system does not exist for Storyboard.